# Cannot use list() more than once on a map object

Tags: python, list, python-3.x

Does anyone one know why:

```
x2 = map(lambda x: x, [2, 4, 6])
print(list(x2)) 
print(list(x2))
```

gives:

```
[2, 4, 6]
[]
```

It is as if I can only use `list` once on the `map` object. I do not understand what is happening.

Comment: because you consume the iterator on `map` the first time.

Comment: use list comprehension: `[x for x in [2,4,6]]`

Comment: Ok, I see now what  you mean  -   I learned something new
The work around I found, if I want to use map() is to do the following :

    x2 = map(lambda x: x, [2, 4, 6])
    x3=list(x2)
    print(list(x3)) 
    print(list(x3)) 

I do not know if it is the best way, but I least I know that I can apply several iterators over the result of map()