# Python not returning filter object

Tags: python, list, function, filter, return

I have this piece of code, where active_airports is a list containing dict elements as follows:

```
{'code' : 'ICAO Code (eg. KMIA)', 'departures' : 8, 'arrivals' : 0}
```

```
def prune_to_xa():
    """
    Prunes the airport list to only XA airports
    Achieves this by checking if ICAO code starts with K, PA, PH, TJ or C
    """
    only_xa_airports = filter(lambda element: element['code'].startswith(("K", "PA", "PH", "TJ", "C")), active_airports)
    return only_xa_airports
```

I can print the filter object inside the function as a list using list(), and I get a correctly filtered list.

When I try to assign the return value to a variable outside the function, it becomes nothing. If I try to print it using list(), I get an empty list.

```
active_airports = prune_to_xa()
print(list(active_airports))
```

If I run this, I get: `[]`

Comment: check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44420135/filter-object-becomes-empty-after-iteration

Answer (score 0):

Your implementation works for me, but the proper way to define a function is to define arguments for inputs (i.e. using globals is bad practice):

```
def prune_to_xa(airports):
    only_xa_airports = [
        element for element in airports
        if element["code"].startswith(("K", "PA", "PH", "TJ", "C"))
    ]
    return only_xa_airports


active_airports = prune_to_xa(active_airports)
print(active_airports)
```

Also note that I have changed the `filter`/`lambda` to the arguably more Pythonic list comprehension.